# JavaScript: Undefined variable error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to store the location value out of the function's scope. The HTML5 geolocation API is what I need. Here is my code:

```
var location={};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function maPosition(position) {

          location.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
          location.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    });

console.log(position.latitude);
console.log(position.longitude);
```

When I run this, I get the error `variable undefined`. This is due to the fact that it might not be available in in the scope of `maPosition`. Since I'm a rookie in JavaScript I was wondering what is the way around it. How can I access the value of `position.coords` out of the scope it's declared in? Can anyone help?

Comment: the last 2 lines `console.log(position.latitude);
console.log(position.longitude);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position` variable is passed to the callback function in `getCurrentPosition`. it's only available inside that function

try:

```
var location={};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function maPosition(position) {

      location.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      location.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log(position.latitude);
      console.log(position.longitude);
      // or you could call another function and pass the value
      //someFunction(position):
});
```

The call to the geolocation services are asyc, so if you want to use the value of `position` you need to either do it in the callback or pass it to another function.

Comment: That's not what i'm trying to do. im' trying to get the value out of the scope the console log is here to show that it's not working . but thank you!

Comment: It still needs to read `location.*` when logging, otherwise it will log undefined

Comment: as you'll see from my answer, the call is asyc, you'll need to use the value inside the function or pass it to another function to deal with